# Keyboard input in Raspberry Pi

Tags: keyboard

I would like to get a keyboard input in my Raspi, but i wouldn't like to plug a keyboard to it. If I've connected my Raspberry pi 3 to a PC, is there any possibility to use PC's keyboard both in the PC and in the Raspy at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: yes, there is a possibility ... what does `at the same time` mean here? ... what do you expect to happen?

Comment: for example, im writting a document in my PC. So everytime the key 'P' is pressed, the raspi detects it and calls a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can share a keyboard over network using
https://github.com/debauchee/barrier. Install it on you RPi:

```
sudo apt -y install barrier
```

and on your PC and point one to each other.

Comment: The thing is that this only eliminates the barrier between the PC and the Raspi. What I would like to do is that when you type sth in your PC, you also type it in the Raspberry.